What is the proper way to retrieve error handling from a compiler to an ide?
I have written my own programming language and have finished the self hosting compiler for it. I am now writing the ide frontend in windows for this compiler backend.
The issue is I created all the error handling in the compiler backend so now that I am creating the ide for this compiler I don't understand how they are suppose to communicate. An ide is suppose to execute the compiler when the run button is pressed, then pass the files that were created in the ide, to the compiler to be parsed and compiled. That's seems pretty straightforward but how do we retrieve the errors from that compiler if there are any? I would think that the errors would somehow need to be passed back to the ide so that we can display that in an error or output window.
So what is the proper way to retrieve error handling from a compiler to an ide?

Visual studio does it by redirecting stdout from the compiler processes and displaying it in its own in-IDE console.

Expanding on what Jonathan said, consider the following: Forget the IDE for a moment. We want to be able to get at most information using ordinary shell/text tools. [As I've done in the past] I want to save info from (e.g.) gcc -v, readelf -a, objdump --disassemble, etc. into a file and have my scripts process it. So, I need the tool(s) to be able to send the data to stdout (or a file). So, I don't want a compiler that can only convey this info via some special protocol that only your IDE understands. So, just have the IDE divert the tool's stdout and read it.

DLLs share code but not data between processes, so do not help for IPC.

@CraigEstey For clarification, in the compiler itself, send the debug info through stdout functions into a file, then just have the ide use its own functions to read the file and display it contents via output window? What about the actual files needing to be compiled themselves? When you say scripts, are you talking a make or the like?

Q1: yes, Q2: no ;-) Just build by whatever means you want (e.g. make, cmake, scons, etc.). By "scripts", I mean utilities that analyze the output of the build process: ld can produce a [text] linker map. gcc can produce .i and/or .s files in addition to .o. The scripts can use readelf/objdump on the .o to get symbol maps and/or disassembly.

You should probably use llvm. It is what clang uses. If your compiler produces an AST (abstract syntax tree), you can feed this to llvm. It will do all the code generation, debug info, generation of object files, etc. It will do this for many different CPU architectures and system platforms. So, your compiler just needs a grammar (.l and .y files) and to generate the AST. llvm probably provides utility functions to do all this.

@CraigEstey The compiler produces it own asm code so it only needs to get assembled and linked separately. I def understand the first part.  I kept seeing it as a whole so when you said temp remove ide and explained it. It made sense. Was only curious about scripts to understood your paragraph better. Just need to understand Q2 better now.

Basically, your compiler should provide most of the features of gcc, clang, such as command arguments like -o, -c, -S, -E, -P, -dM, -L, -l, -I, etc. That is, make your compiler front end compatible with gcc as far as command line arguments go. You're already producing the .s file, which I presume you feed to gas for native x86 code. If that's the goal, fine. If you want to produce mips, arm, s390 code, that's where llvm can help. Give it the AST and it can produce .s files for any CPU it supports. llvm is a suite of tools/APIs for compiler writers.

Again, what are the goals? Design a language? Produce a parser for the language? Code generator for the language (e.g. for x86_64)? Produce an IDE? This can be as little as language syntax/grammar (.y file), parse it to an AST, feed this to llvm. Or, do you need to produce (by hand) the code generator and not just the parser? Do you need to create a custom IDE? Or, just configure (e.g.) eclipse, code:blocks, VS studio, to front your language?

@CraigEstey I apologize. I am not sure I follow on the last two comments. I have a compiler that lexs, parses, has ast, symbol table, code generation. It takes the source files fed to it and compiles into nasm asm so that it can be assembled and linked. I have my own preprocessor that I wrote, that understands it own command line arguments. I should prob make that a separate prog.  That where I am confused. I think I understand the gcc way of doing it but I am not understanding how to handle the files in the graphical way. Create files in ide, compile straight, from directory?

That why I am asking about communication in general because I am defiantly missing a step or two somewhere.

A number of the IDEs (that I mentioned) are compiler/language agnostic. They are just "wrappers" around command line oriented compilers/tools. They have no code generation, etc. They just run gcc under a virtual terminal window, capture (and interpret) the output. They might also run gdb in a separate window for a debugger. (e.g.) When you hit run-under-debugger button, it just feeds a run command to gdb via the pseudo-tty it has set up for gdb. Try looking at the source for ddd. It just feeds cmds to gdb, grabs the output, and displays in a window.

For linux/posix, have a look at man 7 pty. I don't know what the winX equivalent is. And, if you want the IDE to have a code editor, look at gvim and/or neovim. In lieu of pty, you can set up two man 2 pipe to communicate with the given command line tools (but pty, I think, is easier/better. Under linux, you could run a standard IDE under strace to see how it communicates with editors, compilers, and debuggers.

There isn't much magic to this. IDEs commonly parse the output of a compiler. That works reliably as long as the compiler produces output following an agreed-upon pattern. As an exercise run cl.exe against an invalid program source an see if you can guess its output pattern.

The usual way is via a command line and standard output.
Specify arguments to the sub-process on the command line and pass a STARTUPINFO parameter to CreateProcess, set STARTF_USESTDHANDLES in dwFlags and set the hStdOutput and hStdError handles as appropriate.
In the sub-process use those handles to write whatever information the parent needs.
When the sub-process is done use those handles to read whatever the process wrote.
This assumes the usual non-interactive compiler process, that you simply set it running and it does work then returns without taking user input.
